# How do I properly configure SonarLint in Visual Studio Code for a CMake C++ project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, sonarlint

I'm working on a CMake C++ project in Visual Studio Code.  I have the SonarLint plugin installed.  Every time I save one of my source files, I get the error shown in the screenshot below.

[image: SonarLint error message]

When I click "Configure compile commands", I get another message stating that no compilation databases were found with a link to documentation on how to generate one.  I followed the link and discovered that I can set the CMake variable `CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS` to have it generate the database.  However, setting that seems to have no effect since I still get the error after re-configuring my project.

What is the proper way to set that variable?

I'm doing this on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it working by referring to the blog article “[A C&C++ tour of SonarLint for VS Code](https://www.sonarsource.com/blog/a-c-and-cpp-tour-of-sonarlint-for-vs-code/)”.

In the article, it is mentioned that all you need is a compilation database, and there is a link to the [sonarlint-vscode wiki section on how to generate a compilation database for C and C++ analysis](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarlint-vscode/wiki/C-and-CPP-Analysis#1).

You can generate the compilation database using any of the 3 methods mentioned in the wiki, however, I found it faster to generate it using a different method which is not mentioned there.

As explained in the blog article [Makefile Tools December 2021 Update: Problem Matchers and Compilation Database Generation](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/makefile-tools-december-2021-update-problem-matchers-and-compilation-database-generation/), you can use the Makefile Tools extension for VS Code to quickly generate the compilation database.